# Convert iptables rules to pf

Tags: iptables, pf

I would like to ask you how to change following iptable rule:
`iptables -t nat PREROUTING  --source x.x.x.x/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to x.x.x.x:8080`
to pf. I am trying to capture

Comment: There're 2 kinds of PFs in use: modern OpenBSD's PF and legacy-PF which has been ported to a variety of other OSes. Answer would depend on target version hence.

Answer (score 1):

With that info, it could be something like this, where x would be the ips:

```
nat pass on eth0 proto tcp from x.x.x.x/24 to any port 443 rdr-to x.x.x.x port 8080
```

**from** would specify the source.

**to** the destination with the **port**

the part of **rdt-to** would specify the redirection.